# Solve $\ln(y-x) y’ = y \ln (y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

This was a problem I worked on for a while before realising I misread the homework question (it was supposed to be $\ln(y-x) y’ = y \ln (y)$.)

Can anyone tell me if this can be solved (maybe series solutions)?

Comment: Is the equation $\ln(y-x) y’ = y \ln (y)$ or $(y\ln y -x) y’ = y \ln (y)$?

Comment: Could it be that Sebastiano made a wrong edit? It seems to me that the question is about $\ln(−)'=\ln()$, and the homework was $(\ln()−)'=\ln()$. Of course, the question should preferably be in the text and not just in the title.

Comment: This question is about ln(y-x)y’=ylny and the homework was the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the equation is, as in the original post,$$(y\log(y)-x)y’=y \log(y)$$ Switching variables, it becomes
$$(y\log(y)-x)=x'y \log(y)$$ Let $x=\frac z {\log(y)}$ and the equation becomes
$$z'=\log(y)\implies z=y(\log(y)-1)+C$$ that is to say
$$x=y+\frac{C-y}{\log (y)}$$

Comment: Sorry, how do you arrive at $(y\log(y)-x)=x'y \log(y)$? Thank you.

Comment: @manooooh  because $$y'=\dfrac 1{x'}$$  where $x'=\frac {dx}{dy}$